# c# exception handling in textboxes

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am trying to figure out a solution in C# to perform exception handling for multiple textboxes using windows forms.

The user can only enter one or two positive integers in these textboxes and if the user tries to enter more numbers or letters, a tooltip should appear with a warning message?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: You mean you want to validate the user input, right? Well, it all depends on what UI framework you use (Windows.Forms? WPF/UWP?) It would be a good idea to add the respective tag to your question to make clear whether it is about WinForms or WPF...

Comment: So what's stopping you from figuring out a solution? Is something wrong with your computer? You don't know any C# at all? You know some C# but... what? You're getting an error? Post your code. Post the error message. And explain what “exception handling” has to do with anything; detecting whether the user typed numbers or letters into a textbox does not require exception handling.

Comment: @DourHighArch: You mean aside from the .NET Framework being ginormous and him not even knowing the proper Term to google by? I had a possible answer and I do not know how the pattern is called.

Comment: Okay, so yes basic try-catch-statements in C# are fairly straightforward. I am building an application using windows forms in C# and binaryreader/writer. My main point was to catch invalid values that a user might input then try to write the invalid text input which gets converted to byte back to the original file. Currently, I get the dreaded StackOverflow exception which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I meant System Overflow exception

Comment: If you solved your own question, put the solution in the Your Answer box below if it would be of use to other people. After a day or so you can mark your own answer as the solution; doing that marks your question as answered in the UI. Adding “SOLVED” to the title does not mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

For a case like this, I like to do what I call "passive Error Reporting". Rather then throwing exceptions, you take every value (usually strings). But display a message if it does not fit some criteria.

The simple approach is [INotifyDataError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx). It allows you to show one error for each property (it is advantagenous to use a property or a string key in the backend storage).

I know there is a more complex brother that allows Multiple errors per Property/Key. But it is too long since I read it's name, so I can not remember it.

Comment: This, by itself, will not show a tooltip for Windows Forms.

Comment: @RonBeyer: It gives you the base framework to detect errors (and be informed if they change). Wich you can then visualize however you like or the UI Demands: Labels, Tooltips, whatever.

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_

Comment: @celtics33 you’re not a _flat Earther_ by any chance?